# Datepicker not working jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Hi jQuery Mobile's datepicker it is `<input type="text" data-role="date">` I clicked on it not works. How to get this work?
Instead I must use plugin datepicker from cordova?

My code: https://jsbin.com/milafep/edit?html,output this input is on page two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look to the jQuery Mobile [documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/datepicker/).

Datepicker is not a jQuery Mobile widget and is not supported by jQuery Mobile. The documentation suggests to use the jQuery UI widget.